# AngularJs2 'angular not defined' error following starting guide

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting started with AngularJs 2 by following [their quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

which has been working just fine so far.

Now I have moved on to their [displaying data](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html) guide 
but I got stuck and this point.I'm using ES5.

the index :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
        <!-- Angular is working on removing the traceur dependency -->
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="components/display.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <my-app></my-app>
        <display-stuff></display-stuff>
    </body>
</html>
```

The display.js:

```
function DisplayComponent()
{
    this.myOwnVar = 'Chicki chicki Gabriel';
}

DisplayComponent.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'display'
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        template:
            '<p>My name is, hi, my name is who, my name is: {{ myOwnVar }}</p>'
    })
];
```

It says angular is not defined which I think is, since the app.js from the previous tutorial works perfectly fine:

```
(function() {
    var AppComponent = ng
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            template: '<h1>My first Template audited gf</h1>'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {

            }
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    });
})();
```

Comment: instead of using angular.ComponentAnnotation, use the API methods ng.Component and ng.Class as done in app.js

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem, not run away from it.

Comment: The global `angular` was renamed to `ng` in [alpha 30](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/65a767d9b0b2816af86065083108bd517c35ce48).

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: ng.ComponentAnnotation is not a function"

Comment: All the `*Annotations` were renamed to `*Metadata` long time ago.

Comment: what? oh lord, im completely confused now, renaming it shows nothing on the tempalte,  could you please show me a working example?

Answer (score 0):

For a working example, see  https://gist.github.com/lokanx/6bc34b10bbe9cd7c2d59.

display.js

```
(function () {
   var Display = ng.Component({
        selector: 'display',
        templateUrl: 'views/display.html',
        directives: [ng.NgFor, ng.NgIf],
        providers: [Display]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function () {
            this.myName = "Alice";
            this.names = ["Aarav", "Martín", "Shannon"];
        }
    });

    ng.provide("Display", Display);
})();
```

And app.js

```
(function () {
    var AppComponent = ng.Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
        directives: [Display]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function () {}
    });

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      ng.bootstrap(AppComponent);
   });
```

})();

app.html

```
 <h1>My First Angular 2 App </h1>
 <display></display>
```

display.html

```
<p>My name: {{ myName }}</p>
```

And may I suggest you start writing your angular2 code in typescript instead? It is a lot easier.